# square of perimeter divided by are is formula of what?

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing

In this, what is "a"? How to explain it?

```
s=regionprops(L,'Perimeter','Area'); 
a=s.Perimeter^2/s.Area; 
  %use one letter for simplicity,  returns the value for perimeter and area

  % for square ((a>17) && (a<20))
    %for circle ((a>13) && (a<17))
    % for triangle ((a>20) && (a<30))
```

Comment: The comments in the code seem to suggest a guess at the shape of the region

Answer (score 1):

The value of `a` is a measure of the roundness or circularity of the shape `L`. The minimum is achieved for circles:

```
s.Area = pi * r^2
s.Perimeter = 2 * pi * r
a = 4 * pi = 12.566...
```

Other shapes will always have greater values. For instance, for squares:

```
s.Area = l^2
s.Perimeter = 4 * l
a = 16
```

or for equilateral triangles:

```
s.Area = sqrt(3) * l^2 / 4
s.Perimeter = 3 * l
a = 12 * sqrt(3) = 20.78...
```